# React : How to disable button when my function return me a specific value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I woudlike to disable button when my variable `endPool` equal to 1 :

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
          web3: '',
          Amount: '',
          endPool: 0,
        }
        this.getPool = this.getPool(this);
      }
```

My fuction `getPool` return me a specific value in my variable `endPool` and sometimes I get the value "`1`"

```
 render(){
        return(
          <div>
            <button className="pool-button" onClick={this.Bet}><b>W | {this.state.cote} </b></button>
          </div>
        )
```

How can I disable my button `className "pool-button"` when `endPool=1` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<button 
  className="pool-button" 
  onClick={this.Bet} 
  disabled={this.state.endPool === 1}
>
  <b>W | {this.state.cote}</b>
</button>
```

This will disable / not disable the button based on the value in state, if your condition is accurate.